# Rounding in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi trying to round Rate but can't seem to get the correct output. 
Rate infor comes in the follwing format
example 73.9593
example 49.7093
 need the help with getting Rate to round so 73.9593 should be 74 and 49.7093 should be 50

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TEST.Associate,
TEST.Week,
TEST.Function AS FUNCTION,
Sum( TEST.Items ) AS Items,
Sum( TEST.Hours ) AS Hours,
Sum( TEST.Items ) / Sum( TEST.Hours ) AS Rate
FROM
TEST 
    WHERE
TEST.Function = "Pick" 
GROUP BY
TEST.Associate,
TEST.Week,
TEST.Function

HAVING
TEST.Week >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```

Comment: How did you not Google "round mysql" before posting this?

Comment: I did try getting info on google did not work. ROUND(x.x) did not work

Comment: Show us the query you attempted. `ROUND()` is absolutely the right thing to use here, so it'd help us figure out what you messed up.

Comment: I tried a few different ways one of them was I was using ROUND(Sum( Test.Items ) / Sum( SUPER.Hours ),2).. after removing the ,2) it did work. thanks

Comment: Well, yeah, removing the `,2` would work if you want it to round to full digits.

Comment: Please add crucial additional information by editing the original question instead of just posting it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`ROUND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TEST.Associate,
TEST.Week,
TEST.Function AS FUNCTION,
Sum( TEST.Items ) AS Items,
Sum( TEST.Hours ) AS Hours,
ROUND(Sum( TEST.Items ) / Sum( TEST.Hours )) AS Rate
FROM
TEST 
    WHERE
TEST.Function = "Pick" 
GROUP BY
TEST.Associate,
TEST.Week,
TEST.Function

HAVING
TEST.Week >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```

You can test it via simple queries:

```
mysql> select round(73.9593);
+----------------+
| round(73.9593) |
+----------------+
|             74 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select round(49.7093);
+----------------+
| round(49.7093) |
+----------------+
|             50 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: that worked thank you! originally I was using ROUND(Sum( Test.Items ) / Sum( SUPER.Hours ),2) and did not work but your solution worked. thanks

Comment: @RIVERPRO: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Round( Sum( TEST.Items ) / Sum( TEST.Hours ), 0) AS Rate
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just posting some code.

Comment: The question asks how to round rate and the answer to use builtin function.